# The searchController doesn't appear in the navigationItem after reloading the ViewController (Swift 5)

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

In my application, I'm using the searchController that I placed in the navigationItem.
I create a searchController like this:

```
class FirstVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
private var searchController = UISearchController()
var creator: FirstVC?
@IBOutlet var navigationBarItem: UINavigationItem!

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
   searchController = setupSearchController()
   navigationBarItem = searchController
}

private func setupSearchController() -> UISearchController {
        let controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        ...
        return controller
    }
```

If my tableView is empty, then I hide the searchController, otherwise I display it:

```
private func hideSearchBar() {
        navigationBarItem.searchController = nil
    }

private func showSearchBar() {
        navigationBarItem.searchController = searchController
    }

private func reloadCreator(vc: FirstVC) {
        ...
      if !....isEmpty {
        showSearchBar()
      } else {
        hideSearchBar()
    }
```

But when I present a SecondVC above this one (for this I use `navigationController?.showDetailViewController(...)` func) and then dismiss it, the searchController doesn't show up. But if I push the VC and come back, it shows up.
I try to use func `reloadCreator` to reload data in FirstVC when I dismiss my SecondVC, but searchController doesn't appear.

```
@objc private func dismissSecondVC() {
        ...
        guard let vc = creator else { return }
        reloadCreator(vc: vc)
        
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

How can I get the searchController to be displayed?